# Can't get static redirects to work with IIS Url Rewrite 2.0

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting

Running the following IIS URL Rewrite setup locally and can't get it to work (from web.config):

```
        <rewrite>
        <rewriteMaps>
            <rewriteMap name="StaticRedirects">
                <add key="^tvb/" value="/tv/" />
            </rewriteMap>
        </rewriteMaps>
        <rules>
            <rule name="StaticRedirectsRule" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{StaticRedirects: {REQUEST_URI}}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="(.+)" ignoreCase="true" negate="false" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Trying to open the url http://localhost/tvb/ or http://localhost/tvb/?a=b returns a 404 error instead of redirecting me to http://localhost/tv (with or without query string).

I've found similar posts here on stackoverflow and I've tried what they recommended:  recycling the app pool, restarting the IIS service, replacing REQUEST_URI with URL and/or REQUEST_FILENAME but none of these changes made a difference.

Can anyone see where I went wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem, and replacing REQUEST_URI with PATH_INFO fixed the issues.

Here is the link https://forums.iis.net/post/1883056.aspx

Reasoning: 
'This is because REQUEST_URI contains the entire requested URL that includes the query string. Since the keys in the rewrite map do not contain the query string the map lookup fails.'

Answer (score 5):

Well, I managed to find a solution for this myself, so here's what I did:

First, it seems rewriteMap does not support regular expressions, so this doesn't work:

```
<add key="^tvb/" value="/tv/" />
```

instead, it has to be like this:

```
<add key="/tvb/" value="/tv/" />
```

Also, it seems the IIS7 REQUEST_URI variable has changed behavior since the Url Rewrite 2.0 module (and documentation) was released.

Previously, REQUEST_URI only included the path of the url, without domain and query string.

Now, apparently REQUEST_URI in IIS7 works like the one in Apache, i.e. it includes the query string as well, so no wonder this part doesn't work:

```
<add input="{StaticRedirects: {REQUEST_URI}}" ... />
```

instead I had to change it to this:

```
<add input="{StaticRedirects: {SCRIPT_NAME}}" ... />
```

And now the redirects work, both with and without query strings!

Hope this helps someone.

Just found this on serverfault: [IIS Rewrite, rewrite maps and query strings](https://serverfault.com/questions/324384/iis-rewrite-rewrite-maps-and-query-strings/324385#324385).