# Url rewriting rules for static web pages - returning 404 after using url with additional parameters

Tags: iis, iis-7, url-rewriting, http-status-code-404, url-parameters

I use URL Rewriting module for IIS7 - because of URL rewrite for few static files.

Basically I am mapping /pretty-url to /real-file-name.html

So far it is simple.

But after adding query string to pretty url it throws 404 status code. So far I have not found any option to fix this. Any advice, or am I doing something wrong?

Here is the configuration:

```
<rewriteMaps>
  <rewriteMap name="CoolUrls">
<add key="/pretty-url" value="/real-file.html" />
    ... and so on ...
  </rewriteMap>
</rewriteMaps>
```

and:

```
<rules>
  <clear />
    <rule name="Rewrite rule for CoolUrls" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{CoolUrls:{REQUEST_URI}}" pattern="(.+)" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
    </rule>
</rules>
```

Any request with query (any parameters after ? mark) ends with 404 status code.

Comment: Tried appendQueryString setting to false and other relevant options. Maybe some other regex pattern for matching only the part without parameters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you want to be able to add a query string and that this query string has to be appended to the rewritten request. You probably don't want the query string to be included in the matching in your rewritemap. Because that's actually what you are doing with `{CoolUrls:{REQUEST_URI}}` because `{REQUEST_URI}` also contains the query string. You should replace that with `{CoolUrls:{R:0}}`.

Complete rule:

```
<rule name="Rewrite rule for CoolUrls" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{CoolUrls:{R:0}}" pattern="(.+)" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```

**Update:** You should update your rewrite map as `{R:0}` (the URL) does not include the leading slash from the URL. So your rewrite map should be:

```
<rewriteMaps>
    <rewriteMap name="CoolUrls">
        <add key="pretty-url" value="/real-file.html" />
        <add key="another/pretty-url" value="/another/real-file.html" />
        ... and so on ...
    </rewriteMap>
</rewriteMaps>
```

Comment: Sadly did not helped and stopped working at all (no rewrite working). But I think I understand and will try to forge regex for script path and rest of url and hope I will find out something.

Comment: I've updated my answer. You have to modify the rewrite map slightly as the `{R:0}` variable does not include the leading slash.

Comment: Thank you (!!!), it is working now. Just the feeling I don't really know whats going on remains. How is gotten the path (without query) into R:0 when there is no grouping in match url pattern (nor condition pattern).

Comment: The variables with syntax `{R:x}` reference the `url` of the `<match>` tag. `{R:0}` matches the entire URL, where as `{R:1}` matches the first group of the regular expression, `{R:2}` the second group, etc. Variables with the syntax `{C:x}` reference the `pattern` of the `<add>` tags of conditions. When using more than one condition, you should use `trackAllCaptures="true"` in order to be able to reference them all. Which number to use depends on the number of conditions and the number of groups in the regular expression(s). The regular expression test tool in IIS Manager displays them though.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is by pulling `SCRIPT_NAME` instead of `REQUEST_URI` or `R:0`. It will match the leading slash in your rewriteMap keys too. I left out the advanced and optional config (clear, trackAllCaptures, etc) to serve as a better starting point for others:

```
<rules>
    <rule name="Rewrite rule for CoolUrls">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{CoolUrls:{SCRIPT_NAME}}" pattern="(.+)" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
    </rule>
</rules>
```

Answer (score 0):

This fixed the issue: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45555140/1967211
Need to use PATH_INFO instead of REQUEST_URI